# How does std::remove perform compared to std::find for std::vector?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, c++17, big-o

**Background**

I recently refactored some code that placed actors in a world. One actor per room.

My original implementation used a closed set `std::vector` to keep track of indexes of rooms that were no longer available:

```cpp
void RoomsAndCorridorsMapGenerator::PlaceActors() noexcept {
    const int room_count = static_cast<int>(rooms.size());
    auto closed_set = std::vector<std::size_t>{};
    closed_set.reserve(room_count);
    for(auto* actor : _map->_actors) {
        const auto room_idx = [&]() {
            auto idx = static_cast<std::size_t>(MathUtils::GetRandomIntLessThan(room_count));
            while(std::find(std::begin(closed_set), std::end(closed_set), idx) != std::end(closed_set)) {
                idx = static_cast<std::size_t>(MathUtils::GetRandomIntLessThan(room_count));
            }
            closed_set.push_back(idx);
            return idx;
        }(); //IIIL
        actor->SetPosition(IntVector2{rooms[room_idx].CalcCenter()});
    }
}
```

That is:

1. Generate a random index.
2. Search the vector for the index generated.
3. If found, go to step 1.
4. Add the newly generated room index to the closed set.
5. For each actor, continue from step 1.

My refactored implementation used an open set:

```cpp
void RoomsAndCorridorsMapGenerator::PlaceActors() noexcept {
    auto open_set = std::vector<std::size_t>{};
    open_set.resize(rooms.size());
    std::iota(std::begin(open_set), std::end(open_set), std::size_t{0u});
    for(auto* actor : _map->_actors) {
        const auto room_idx = [&]() {
            auto idx = open_set[static_cast<std::size_t>(MathUtils::GetRandomIntLessThan(static_cast<int>(open_set.size())))];
            open_set.erase(std::remove(std::begin(open_set), std::end(open_set), idx), std::end(open_set));
            return idx;
        }(); //IIIL
        actor->SetPosition(IntVector2{rooms[room_idx].CalcCenter()});
    }
}
```

i.e.:

1. Pre-generate the list of available indexes, based on the number of rooms.
2. Pick a random value from the list.
3. Remove that value from the list.
4. For each actor, continue from step 2.

This simplified the code and the algorithm, but I'm not sure of the complexity.

**Question**

How does `std::find` to a vector compare to `std::remove` both in time and complexity?

I'm not sure if the repeated appending/erase-remove idiom also has an effect.

Comment: Both linear in the size of the vectors. If these containers are big enough, it might be worth shifting entirely from a vector to an unordered_set to get the O(1) insertion, lookup, and removal, but that'd be something you want to actually benchmark.

Comment: That's really one of the things you would have to benchmark, or dump to assembly and compare. (under several optimization levels) Unfortunately, dumping to assembly with containers involved generally produces a rather large assembly source that you would have to manually whittle down to the critical section and compare.

Comment: A better algorithm: generate a list of indexes, shuffle it (e.g. with `std::shuffle`), then just take indexes sequentially from the randomized sequence. This approach is linear, yours is quadratic.